# ND-JSON Split in SFTP

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, filesplitting, ndjson

I have a large ND-JSON file in SFTP (~20K lines). Is there a way to generate sub files out of this (~500 lines each) and place in another folder in SFTP?

Does Mule 4 has the capability to split a large file and write in SFTP? Or is there a need for a Java component?

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the input file is parsed as NDJSON, you can use the [DataWeave function divideBy()](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dw-arrays-functions-divideby) to separate the array read from the file into subarrays of n elements.

Example:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/java
import * from dw::core::Arrays
---
payload divideBy 500
```

Then you should be able to use a  to process each segment and output an NDJSON file inside.

Comment: Thank you for this. Much appreciated!